# Pass the triggering repository details to Integration Tests from VSTest.Console.exe

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest.console.exe

I can able to run the VS integration tests from the build on the build machine in **TFS Azure Release pipelines**.

```
C:\ci\vstest.console.exe C:\ci\netcoreapp3.1\API.Smartbox.dll /TestCaseFilter:"Category=Repo1" /inIsolation
```

Here I want to filter out any required tests that I want to execute on a certain environment with /TestCaseFilter option by passing the repository details parameter:

```
/TestCaseFilter:"Category=passParameter"
```

Here I am trying to pass the parameter to the **Category** automatically as a **RepositoryName** in the TFS Azure Release pipelines.

Eg. If a build is triggered from a **Repo1** then this name should be pass to the **Category** field and only **Repo1** related tests should gets run, like wise if the build is triggered from **Repo2** then this name should gets pass to the field **Category** and its related tests will get trigger.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the triggering repository details to test parameter, you can use the predefined variable: `$(BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME)`.

This variable will contain the repo name information. You can use the variable in your command.

For example:

```
C:\ci\vstest.console.exe C:\ci\netcoreapp3.1\API.Smartbox.dll /TestCaseFilter:"Category=$(BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME)" /inIsolation
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)